# Why does setFullYear method concatonated to new Date() return milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, date

I was playing around with some code and to shorten my code I wanted to do something like this:

```
//This sets the date to milliseconds
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML= new Date().setFullYear(2020);

//This sets the date to GMT date notation
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(2020);

document.getElementById('date').innerHTML= d;
```

What is going on here? Why can't I concatonate and directly call the method on the new Date method. Weird thing is that it tries to do something but fails somehow and falls back to milliseconds. Someone can shed some light on it?

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5atb3qtv/

Comment: Because the return value of  [Date.prototype.setFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) is `[...]New timestamp value for the current object.[...]`

Comment: @t.niese Thanks, so it is not first converting the date to an object and then calling the setFullYear method on it. It just feels weird that you can't do that but there will be a good reason for that.

Comment: Well if you expect that `new Date().setFullYear(2020)` will return the Date object then you should also expect that for `document.getElementById('date').innerHTML` the `getElementById('date')` would not return the element with the id `date` but `document`. `new Date()` creates the Date object on which you call `setFullYear(2020)`, the return value of `setFullYear(2020)` is then the result of your expression `new Date().setFullYear(2020)` and the result of the expression is the value assigned.

Comment: @t.niese Ok, I get where you getting at. So I am just calling the setFullYear method. I was totally off here...I really was thinking I could directly call the method on a new instance of Date. Well, I keep learning every day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in the first case you're alerting the return value of calling the `.setFullYear` method, which returns a value in milliseconds. In the second example, you're alerting a Date object, on which the `.toString` method will be called, resulting in the date format you see.

Edit:

If you're still confused about why the return value of the method is given instead of the date in case one, think of it like this: if you call a method of an object like `document.getElementById`, you expect to get the result of calling that method are the return value, in this case an `Element`. You wouldn't expect to get `document` back. It's the same in your case. You're calling `(new Date()).setFullYear()` which returns a number and expecting it to return the date object it's a member of, which wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. So it does not evaluate the date first and then call the setFullYear method on it? Seems counter intuitive. But thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking about the first case or the second case?

Comment: `new Date((new Date()).setFullYear(2020))` may be what you're looking for in case 1. However, that is needlessly messy.

Comment: First case, I don't get why I can't directly call the setFullYear method on it. Why isn't it evaluating to an object directly with all the methods attached to it.

Comment: I edited my answer to help explain what I think you're getting at.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem now. I was just calling `setFullYear()`. I don't get why it confused me so much.